# Ruby library for manipulating existing PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm searching for a library to edit already existing PDF's and add a watermark to each page, for example. Could also be blank every other page etc.

There seem to be a few PDF libraries out there, but only very few of them can edit existing PDF's and I'm a bit lost on which way to go.

Any recommendations?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about using a java library through jruby. I'm not hearing a lot of good things about the PDF libraries for ruby.
Something to think about if you are getting desperate.

Comment: Hmm, that was not what I hoped to hear, but had some how expected it. There seem to be some good libraries for creating PDF's (like Prawn), editing and reading them is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a prawn branch that has this functionality. Unfortunately it's yet to be merged upstream, but I'm hopeful it will happen soon. For more information, try searching the prawn google group for "templates".

Comment: My branch is now part of the latest official prawn release, 0.11.1