# Add text to existing pdf using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have an rails application that is joining any count of pdf files. Now I need to add a numbering to the joined pdf using ruby.

Is there a state of the art way to add text or other content to an existing pdf file using ruby?

Comment: Prawn is a possibility - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185942/how-to-edit-or-write-on-existing-pdf-with-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked well for me...

```
Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf", :template => "/path/to/template.pdf") do
  text "This is a text in a copied pdf.", :align => :center
end
```

Comment: Be aware that Prawn is not supporting templates since December 2013:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/prawn-ruby/S6gXA-i0-do

Answer (score 2):

Working with PDF's is really challenging in Ruby/Rails (so I have found out!)

This is the way I was able to add text dynamically to a PDF in rails.

add this gem to your gem file `gem "combine_pdf"`

and then you can use code like this:

```
# get the record from the database to add dynamically to the pdf
user = User.last

# get the existing pdf
pdf = CombinePDF.load "#{Rails.root}/public/pdf/existing_pdf.pdf"

# create a textbox and add it to the existing pdf on page 2
pdf.pages[1].textbox "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}", height: 20, width: 70, y: 596, x: 72

# output the new pdf which now contains your dynamic data
pdf.save "#{Rails.root}/public/pdf/output#{Time.now.to_s}.pdf"
```

You can find details of the textbox method here:
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/combine_pdf/0.2.5/CombinePDF/Page_Methods#textbox-instance_method

I spent days on this working through a number of different gems:
`prawn`
`wicked_pdf`
`pdfkit`
`fillable_pdf`

But this was by far the most smooth solution for me as of 2019.

I hope this saves someone a lot of time so they don't have to go through all the trial and error I had to with PDF's!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CombinePDF](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) for that.

I wrote it because Prawn dropped their template support and I needed a native replacement.

Your code might look something like this:

```
pdf = CombinePDF.new
pdf << CombinePDF.new("file1.pdf")
pdf << CombinePDF.new("file2.pdf")
pdf.number_pages
pdf.save "output.pdf"
```

look at the documentation for the different formatting options - I love to surround the numbering with a rounded box (it's in the features, should be easy to play with).