# Edit existing pdf file metadata with ruby (Apply Password protection)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, prawn

I am uploading a pdf file using paperclip to s3. I want to apply password protection on the fly to the uploaded pdf file.

I tried to use the code given in question [How to edit or write on existing PDF with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185942/how-to-edit-or-write-on-existing-pdf-with-ruby)! to edit existing pdf file (the tmp file used by the paperclip) and try to apply password protection using

```
Prawn::Document.generate("tmp/abc.pdf",:template => params[:ebook].path) do  encrypt_document(:user_password => 'foo', :owner_password => 'bar',
                :permissions => { :print_document => false,
                                  :modify_contents => false,
                                  :copy_contents => false,
                                  :modify_annotations => false }    end
```

Is the template support still exist in prawn or it had been deprecated as i didn't find anything regarding template in the [prawn manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf)!  ?

Is there any other way or any other gem to do so ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` was removed in version `0.13.0` because it was too buggy :

> Support for templates was dropped in Prawn 0.13.0, disabled by default in 0.14.0, and extracted in 0.15.0.
>
> This gem includes the extracted templates code, which is completely unsupported, but provides the old functionality that was in Prawn 0.12.0 for years.

source : https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn-templates

As he said, you can try to add the library to your current Prawn installation.

---

Otherwise you can use `pdftk` with `Open3` module (http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) :

```
require 'open3'

file_name = 'hello_world_1.pdf' # input
file_name_output = 'hello_world_2.pdf' # output

usr = 'foo'
pwd = 'bar'

pdftek = './pdftk.exe' # tested on windows

Open3.popen3("#{pdftek} #{file_name} output #{file_name_output} owner_pw #{pwd} user_pw #{usr}") do |stdin,stdout,stderr|
    # ...
end
```

There is also a wrapper for ruby but I haven't test it yet : https://github.com/tcocca/active_pdftk

Comment: Thanks alot psal i had done it already using the same way you suggest, using cli tool pdftk on ubuntu and running a system 'pdftk input output ' command in my code. Thanks for reply