# Including pdf-editing functionality in my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

```
Rails 7
```

One of the requirements for my application, is to have the user fill out some tax information, using a fillable PDF form. While there are some gems that allow me to create a PDF, I only saw one recommendation:

[Rails-Pdf Editing Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489870/rails-editing-pdf-template)

But the post is 7+ years old, and when I checked the pdf-form gem, it seems the last time anyone did work on it, was about 7 years ago.

I don't necessarily want to create my own solution, and I would be happy to crate a frame, within my app, that takes the user to another site where they can edit the PDF, as long as it could be saved back to my own server.

Any recommendations?

Comment: What is wrong with a 7 year old gem? The PDF specification goes back much farther than that. "Any recommendations?" You should be asking here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There have been 3 major Rails updates since. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) to do this. It supports filling out AcroForm forms, if you wanna do it this. Or you can load the PDF and overlay the information yourself, using everything that is available in the [Canvas](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/reference/api/HexaPDF/Content/Canvas.html) class.

(N.b. I'm the author of HexaPDF and the library is dual-licensed under the AGPL and a commercial license.)