# Merge PDF files containing Optional Content - Ruby 2.2.4 - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, osx-elcapitan, ruby-2.2

In a Rails 4 project I have been tasked with merging an “about” page to the end of PDF documents that have been uploaded via Paperclip.

The issue is that some of the uploaded pdfs contain [optional content](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/developing-with-pdf/9781449327903/ch10.html). I started out using [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) but it does not support files with optional content as explained [here](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf/issues/28). I have tried [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/) but it no longer support this functionality. I finally found the [PDF Toolkit gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-toolkit)  but the documentation does not say anything about optional content support. [PDF Toolkit](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) is a command line tool that has been wrapped in a Gem and therefore operates outside of the Rails application. I have tried using these command line [examples](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/) in my CLI: `pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output out_file.pdf` but the terminal just hangs indefinitely.

The gem's documentation [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pdf-toolkit/PDF/Toolkit/Native) is very unclear (to me) and may be the source of my issues.

My hope is to find advice on how to accomplish this using PDF Toolkit OR a better library for merging PDFs with optional content.

I have gotten this far by researching Stack Overflow questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185942/how-to-edit-or-write-on-existing-pdf-with-ruby) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/merge-convert-multiple-pdf-files-into-one-pdf)

My OS is OSX 10.11.6

```
existing_pdf_path = @report.document.file.path

# Create a html template and convert it to pdf
about_company_html = render_to_string("_about_company.html.erb", layout: false)

about_company_pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(about_company_html, orientation: 'Landscape')

# Save about_company_pdf to file in tmp/pdf
about_company_pdf_path = Rails.root.join('tmp/pdf', 'about_company_partial.pdf').to_s
File.open(about_company_pdf_path, 'wb') { |file| file << about_company_pdf }

# Create and save a blank target file we will save everything to
combined_pdf_path = Rails.root.join('tmp/pdf', 'combined.pdf').to_s
FileUtils.touch(combined_pdf_path)

# This returns false OR just hangs depending on my exact syntax, no error or backtrace
result = PDF::Toolkit.pdftk( *%w(existing_pdf_path about_company_pdf_path cat output combined_pdf_path) )
```

I have tried as many variations of the above call to `pdftk` as I can find or think of. For example `PDF::Toolkit.pdftk( existing_pdf_path, about_lux_pdf_path, 'cat', 'output', combined_pdf_path )` with no results.

Comment: Your link to CombinePDF mentions a PR... Did you try `CombinePDF.load(about_company_pdf_path, :allow_optional_content)`? Also, is it possible to use WickedPdf without optional content? I didn't try this, but what about the `print_media_type: true`?

Comment: Nick, did you ever figure this out?