# How to populate values to input elements present in existing PDF using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, pdf-parsing

I have a PDF with various input elements, check boxes, radio buttons. How can I populate values to those elements using ruby?

Comment: Any piece of code which you tried and stuck with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit or write on existing PDF with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185942/how-to-edit-or-write-on-existing-pdf-with-ruby)

Comment: @orde But it is replacing the entire content in a page. But what I need is populate value directly to a input box in a pdf.

Comment: by not providing a sample of the code you have worked on you are implying you want the answer to be written for you from scratch.

Comment: I have a PDF with several input boxes. What I need is to find a specific input box and populate value into it. I didn't ask to code from scratch. I have already tried out the link given by @orde but that didn't work out for me.